# Pass a value from button to input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to pass a value from a button to an input value with Javascript.
What i have right now is this

this inside a javascript file

```
var test2 = 5;
appendeddatahtml = '<div class="test1"><button id="btn" type="button" value="' + test2 + '">This is it!</button></div>';
$("#test1").append(appendeddatahtml);
```

And this is the form above the script

```
<input type="text" name="latlon" id="latlon" style="display: none; " value="" />
```

First i tried to make an alert with this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    alert("The button was clicked.");
  });
});
```

But it didn't alerted anything.
Is there any way to pass the value from the button to the input value?

Comment: `$("#btn").click(function(){
    alert("The button was clicked.");
});` this code should be put after `$("#test1").append(appendeddatahtml); ` no need for `document.ready`

Comment: id's should be unique on a page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are adding it dynamically you need **[`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here. So just add click as below:

```
$(document).on('click',"#btn",function(){
    alert("The button was clicked.");
});
```

**[DEMO Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/p6c9zzL0/)**

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have created the button dynamically via code during runtime and for such elements you need to use live or on events

http://api.jquery.com/on/

this one will help

example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', "#btn", function() {
        alert('here');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

working here just remove $(document).ready()

```js
var test2 = 5 ;
appendeddatahtml = '<div class="test1"><button id="btn" type="button" value="'+test2+'">This is it!</button></div>';
 $("#test1").append(appendeddatahtml); 

  $("#btn").click(function(){
    alert("The button was clicked.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="latlon" id="latlon" style="display: none; " value="" />
<div id="test1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not  created the element first.

You forgot $();

```
var test2 = 5 ;

 appendeddatahtml = $('<div class="test1"><button id="btn" type="button" value="'+test2+'">This is it!</button></div>');
   $("#test1").append(appendeddatahtml);
```

Comment: sorry but this is not a good answer, everythings inside ' ' is render as html expect variables like `test2` so the $() here it just a text try to run your code and you will see

Comment: Oops! Sorry. I my bad

Comment: anyway the problem wasn't from this, is not make no sense to add $()....[ in jquery we $ to access the DOM element plz read more about jquery/javascript]

Answer (score 0):

link to a working example of what you wanted is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8sf3q3gw/1/)

html code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="latlon" id="latlon" style="display: block; " value="" />
<div id="test1">
</div>
```

javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var test2 = 5 ;
    var appendeddatahtml = '<div class="test1"><button id="btn" type="button" value="'+test2+'">This is it!</button></div>';
                        $("#test1").append(appendeddatahtml);
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        alert("The button was clicked. "+this.value);
        document.getElementById('latlon').value = this.value;
    });
});
```